# Python dictionary delete key

Tags: python, json, key

I'm starting with Python and I'm stuck now. I have to get just the key 'text' from a long list in .txt like:

```
{"delete":"status":"id":294512601600258048,"id_str":"294512601600258048","user_id":90681582,"user_id_str":"90681582"}, "timestamp_ms":"1410368494083"}}
```

and

```
{
    "created_at": "Wed Sep 10 17:01:33 +0000 2014",
    "id": 509748524897292288,
    "id_str": "509748524897292288",
    "text": "@Brenamae_ I WHALE SLAP YOUR FIN AND TELL YOU ONE LAST TIME: GO AWHALE",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": 509748106015948800,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "509748106015948800",
    "in_reply_to_user_id": 242563886,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "242563886",
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": "Brenamae_",
    "user": "id": 175160659,
    "id_str": "175160659",
    "name": "Butterfly",
    "screen_name": "VanessaLilyWan",
    "location": "Canada, Montreal",
    "url": "http:\/\/instagram.com\/vanessalilywan",
    "description": "British youtubers. 'Nuff said.",
    "protected": false,
    "verified": false,
    "followers_count": 118,
    "friends_count": 180,
    "listed_count": 2,
    "favourites_count": 319,
    "statuses_count": 10221,
    "created_at": "Thu Aug 05 20:03:16 +0000 2010",
    "utc_offset": -36000,
    "time_zone": "Hawaii",
    "geo_enabled": false,
    "lang": "en",
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "is_translator": false,
    "profile_background_color": "B2DFDA",
    "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme13\/bg.gif",
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme13\/bg.gif",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "profile_link_color": "93A644",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "EEEEEE",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "FFFFFF",
    "profile_text_color": "333333",
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/470701406245376000\/2aXDrauR_normal.jpeg",
    "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/470701406245376000\/2aXDrauR_normal.jpeg",
    "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/175160659\/1404361640",
    "default_profile": false,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "following": null,
    "follow_request_sent": null,
    "notifications": null
}, "geo": null, "coordinates": null, "place": null, "contributors": null, "retweet_count": 0, "favorite_count": 0, "entities": {
    "hashtags": [],
    "trends": [],
    "urls": [],
    "user_mentions": [{
        "screen_name": "Brenamae_",
        "name": "I-G-G-Bye",
        "id": 242563886,
        "id_str": "242563886",
        "indices": [0, 10]
    }],
    "symbols": ]
}, "favorited": false, "retweeted": false, "possibly_sensitive": false, "filter_level": "medium", "lang": "en", "timestamp_ms": "1410368493668"
}
```

So I have that 2 kinds of keys, and as far as I could go is:

```
    import json
with open('salida_tweets.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        texto=json.loads(line)
        objetos=texto.get('text')           
        print(objetos)
```

> None
>
> @Brenamae_ I WHALE SLAP YOUR FIN AND TELL YOU ONE LAST TIME: GO AWHALE

But in the print the first one still appears as 'None' and I need the clean text to mix it with another file.

Can someone help me?

**EDIT**: 
Sorry I hadn't clarified, I need to separate the "text" line contained in the second line. I need it to mix it with a file that contains several words and  numbers. For example:

for this

> "text": "@Brenamae_ I WHALE SLAP YOUR FIN AND TELL YOU ONE LAST TIME:
>   GO AWHALE"

I have to mix it with

> SLAP       -3 
>   LAST       -1

To get: 1.Tweet -4

So I can get an score for each 'text'.

Comment: The json object on the first line does not seem to have a `"text"` key

Comment: You have a blank line between the two JSON objects in the file. Does that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.get` method returns `None` when searching for a key in a dictionary that doesn't exist, so rather than always printing `objetos`, you could check the return value from `texto.get('text')` first.

E.g.

```
import json

with open('salida_tweets.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        texto = json.loads(line)
        objetos = texto.get('text')

        # implement logic
        if objetos:
            print(objetos)
```

That way, your code won't print if the `text` key does not exist.

Comment: that was just I'm looking for, I was close!, thank you I'm learning little by little

Comment: Another question, how can I use each value of `objetos` given, for example:

I got angry because of the Tv Show
Its really annoying that noise

To give it a value from another dictionary that contains: happy: 5, annoying: 1

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove a key from a dictionary, use the "pop" method.

```
dictionary.pop(key[, default])
```

If you don't care about the value of the key you are removing and don't want to test if it actually exists before removing, you can simply do:

```
text = dictionary.pop('text', None)
```

This will make the variable "text" the value of dictionary['text'] or None if the key doesn't exist.

However, your question seems to be unclear -- it sounds like you don't want a key named 'text' from the object but the value of a key in the object which happens to be text?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, is my first time with python so I can't clarify the concepts.

Comment: I just wanted to print the key 'text', because if I use .get the key ['delete'] appeared as 'None'